# Can I override a method's return value in a breakpoint?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lldb

```
- (BOOL)mySetting
{
  return [myObject returnYes];
}
```

For a method such as the above, is it possible to add a breakpoint with a debugger command so that the `-mySetting` method automatically returns a different value (such as `NO`) when the breakpoint is enabled?

I'm looking for an option where the debugger doesn't have to interrupt execution of the app, (a.k.a. has "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" turned on).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While zylenv's answer will work, it'll require you to create a temporary variable and recompile/launch.

The proper way to do this would be to use lldb's `thread return` command. It is used like this:

[image: thread return NO]

A good blog post explaining its usage (and a bunch of other cool LLDB stuff) is [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/).

Comment: This does not seem to work with Swift in Xcode 10.2

Comment: If you wanted that in Swift, you'd use `thread return false`

Answer (score 3):

You can use lldb debugger to change the return value of the method.
Just did like below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @zylenv, however I'm looking for possibly a debugger command that will do this without stopping execution. I'll edit my question to reflect.

Comment: I have update my answer, and hope this will be help.